# How to set multiple environments for Firebase

Tags: firebase

For my project I use staging and production environment.
fileReplacements property inside angular.json is used to change files:

```
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  },
  {
    "replace": "src/app.html",
    "with": "src/app.prod.html"
  }
]
```

to change between environments .firebaserc files is used.

Now I need to use different firebase config files per environment ( firebase.json and firebase.prod.json )
Is it possible to do it? I thought to use predeploy scrips, but don't know how

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have done it using single .firebaserc file. You can add different targets to deploy.

***firebase target:apply type target-name resource-name***

ref: [ https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets && https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/ ]

// firebase.json

```
"hosting": [
    {
    "target": "prod",
      "public": "dist/<folder_name>,
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

// .firebaserc file
// Sample: here the "projects" are your targets

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "staging-project",
    "dev": "staging-project",
    "prod": "prod-project"
  },
  "targets": {
    "staging-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "stage": [
          "staging-project"
        ],
        "admin-stage": [
          "your-admin-stage"
        ],
        "admin-prod": [
          "your-admin-prod"
        ],
        "prod": [
          "prod-project"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

// in the build script

```
firebase use dev
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules,hosting:stage,functions...
```

Comment: Awesome! Brilliant. Thank you

Comment: Hmm.. Have you faced with the problem when you run separately "firebase use staging AND firebase deploy --only hosting:staging" commands it runs, but when you run the script "firebase use staging && firebase deploy --only hosting:staging" it fails with Error "No public directory specified, can't deploy hosting"

Comment: You need to modify public directory in firebase.json file

Comment: Update outputDirectory in angular.json for each build. Put same directory path in firebase.json for each build

Comment: The problem was with firebase-tools. Simply removed local one and updated local and and no more problem.